# Unload Data from Web View

Tags: ios, uiwebview

My app shows a table view with a list of articles from an RSS feed.  When the user selects a row it opens a web view controller to show the article.  This all works fine.  The only issue I have is that when the user goes back to the table view and they select a different article, the web view initially shows the old article until the new one gets loaded.  How can I have it remove the old data from the web view?

Here is my didSelectRowAtIndexPath method in the tableview:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:webViewController animated:NO];

    // Grab the selected item
    RSSItem *entry = [[channel items]objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];

    // Construct a URL with the link string of the item
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[entry link]];

    // Construct a request object with that URL
    NSURLRequest *req = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    // Load the request into the web view
    [[webViewController webView]loadRequest:req];
    webViewController.hackyURL = url;
}
```

And here is the web view controller:

```
#import "WebViewController.h"
#import "TUSafariActivity.h"
#import "SVProgressHUD.h"

@implementation WebViewController
@synthesize webView=webView, hackyURL=hackyURL;

- (void)loadView
{
    // Create an instance of UIWebView as large as the screen
    CGRect screenFrame = [[UIScreen mainScreen]applicationFrame];
    UIWebView *wv = [[UIWebView alloc]initWithFrame:screenFrame];
    webView = wv;
    NSLog(@"%@",webView.request.URL);
    // Tell web view to scale web content to fit within bounds of webview
    [wv setScalesPageToFit:YES];

    [self setView:wv];
}

- (UIWebView *)webView
{ 
    return (UIWebView *)[self view];
}

- (void) showMenu
{
    NSURL *urlToShare = hackyURL;
    NSArray *activityItems = @[urlToShare];
    TUSafariActivity *activity = [[TUSafariActivity alloc] init];

    __block UIActivityViewController *activityVC = [[UIActivityViewController alloc]initWithActivityItems:activityItems applicationActivities:@[activity]];
    activityVC.excludedActivityTypes = @[UIActivityTypeAssignToContact, UIActivityTypePostToWeibo, UIActivityTypeSaveToCameraRoll];

    [self presentViewController:activityVC animated:YES completion:^{activityVC.excludedActivityTypes = nil; activityVC = nil;}];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.

    UIBarButtonItem *systemAction = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAction target:self action:@selector(showMenu)];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = systemAction;
}

@end
```

Comment: use [tablview reloaddata]; and check it

Comment: I'm not having an issue with the table view.  The problem is with the web view.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can clear the web view by loading a blank document into it as the first line of `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [[webViewController webView] loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"about:blank"]]];

    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Better to maintain one tag in value in "Tableview did select" method,and maintain the same tag value in web view loading view controller also.